# getting error in below code

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am getting missing parenthesis error in below for REPLACE function

```
   declare 
file_name varchar2(10):= 'emp.csv';
begin
execute immediate 'CREATE TABLE emp_external
  (
  EMPNO NUMBER(4),
  emp_name varchar2(100),
   HIREDATE DATE
  )
 ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
  (TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY import
  ACCESS PARAMETERS
  (RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
   LOAD WHEN
    (HIREDATE != BLANKS )
  fields terminated by '''||','||''' 
  ( EMPNO,
  replace(emp_name,'''||'"'||','||''||'''),
  HIREDATE DATE '||'yyyymmdd'||'
   )
   )
  LOCATION ('''||file_name||''')
  )
  REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED';
 end;
```

when i am querying the external table .its giving me the error "EMP_NAME" is bad identifier

Comment: Have you counted left ( and right ) ?

Comment: haan but i m not getting where to put it .its giving error in field replace(emp_name,'||'"'||','||''||'),

Comment: A little tip: your code will be easier to maintain if you don't use the `||` operator to concatenate static strings.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not used to plsql but don't you miss a comma ?

> EMPNO NUMBER(4),
>   emp_name varchar2(100),<------ Here ?
>   HIREDATE DATE
>     )

Comment: What exact modification on emp_name from your file do you expect this replace function to do ?

Comment: MY file looks like 
103,"ABC",12-03-15        
104,"ERT",12-03-15

Comment: does it work if you remove the replace function ?
`fields terminated by '''||','||''' 
  ( EMPNO,
  emp_name,
  HIREDATE DATE '||'yyyymmdd'||'
   )`